# How to draw charts/graphs on ROR web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

Is there any API to draw charts/graphs in ROR web app. I need the data to be drawn from my database (Sqlite3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Jquery highcharts

```
  http://www.highcharts.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

Install [this](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) gem. Go through the [wiki](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts/wiki) section. Seems pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

[Highcharts-rails gem](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails) can help you. Also, there's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts) describing what to do